# Numeric limit & offset based pagination in DynamoDB (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I want to implement numeric limit and offset based pagination in DynamoDB [similar to Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/queries-limit.html).

My API look something like this: `http://foo.bar/user?offset=50&limit=20`.

What's the best way to do this in Java without risking `OutOfMemoryError` considering DynamoDB [uses `ExclusiveStartKey` and `LastEvaluatedKey` to paginate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination)?

EDIT:

Let's assume offset based pagination is a hard-requirement and I don't know the 'prior' page. My API contract have `offset` and `limit` query params as described above. I'm not looking for "don't do offset based pagination" answers.

Comment: Offset based pagination (0, 20, 40, 60. ...) for 20 records _versus_ a search for the last key on prior page + 21 records. The latter can be much faster. _(Just averting about the latter smart pagination technique)_

Comment: Thanks @joop-eggen, but let's assume offset based pagination is a hard-requirement here (I'll add an EDIT to clarify).

Comment: Also @JoopEggen, let's assume I don't know the prior page, I don't keep that state

Comment: (It is indeed a technique to overcome a slow db offset access, requiring holding and juggling with data. Not something to put in a code design.)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now @JoopEggen, I can have a separate 'jump table' holding the start key for each 'bucket'. Now if I need to deep-page, I can jump to the nearest 'bucket' instead of having to traverse from the start. But this require me to maintain this jump table somehow when the source table is updated. It's an interesting idea. I wonder if there's a library / pattern that can help implementing this.

Comment: It can be done lazily; I do not know which pagination libraries use it Encountering it here (?) was a suprise. A cache of page keys, possibly reduced to pages 100, 200, 300, ... or such is imaginable. I wish I new a term for this technique to search for.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at [how PaginatedList work in the sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/PaginatedList.java#L203), it seems the most efficient way is to use `ITERATION_ONLY` pagination loading strategy in the config, and do something like this:

```java
DynamoDBMapperConfig config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder()
                       .withPaginationLoadingStrategy(ITERATION_ONLY)
                       .build();
PaginatedQueryList<MyUser> users = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyUser.class, myQueryExpression, config);
// This iterator will fetch 1MB worth of data 'on-demand'
Iterator<MyUser> userIterator = users.iterator();
skip(iterator, offset);
List<MyUser> aPageOfUser = collect(iterator, limit);
```

Of course I'll incur the cost of implementing my own `skip` and `collect` method there. Is there a better / more-concise way to do this?

EDIT:

It seems I can utilise [IteratorUtils from commons-collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html) to have the `skip` and `collect` for free:

```
Iterator<MyUser> userIterator = IteratorUtils.boundedIterator(users.iterator(), offset, limit);
List<MyUser> aPageOfUser = IteratorUtils.toList(userIterator);
```